# Wrong drawable color with hardware acceleration

Tags: android

My app is hardware accelerated by default (android:hardwareAccelerated="true" set in manifest).

I have a drawable which i set as a background for a view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#666666" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

</shape>
```

Also i have another view:

```
 <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="#666666" />
```

Line width and color should be the same for both. And they are same if i set

```
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

But!
If i do not set software layer type for the view with drawable background, i get 2 different lines:

-the line with color background is ok,

-another one becomes 2px wide, drawn with 2 colors: #333333 and #191919.

Can you please help me? Why does it behave this way? And how can i fix this without disabling hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 1dp line is too wide for me. I need the narrowest line possible and 1px is what fits my requirements.

I actually managed to solve this.
Indeed 1px shape lines are rendered incorrectly with hardware acceleration on, there is nothing you can do with it. 
Instead i used a 9patch drawable in nodpi directory. It displays exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Use density-independent pixels (dp) instead or regular ones (px)

```
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#666666" />
```

and

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#666666" />
```